# SQL Azure Daily Automatic and Keep Unlimited Time

Tags: azure-sql-database, database-backups

### SQL Azure Daily Automatic and Keep Unlimited Time

I am trying to do the azure tutorial: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f6899710-634e-425a-969d-8db1267e9471

But the STORAGE ACCOUNT dont show any option, and I already had a storage account.

Comment: What version are you using V11 or V12 and what performance tier is the DB?  Also which portal are you using manage.azure.com or portal.azure.com?

Comment: https://manage.windowsazure.com. Where can I see if is V11 or V12?

I did not see the option on portal.azure.com.

Comment: V12, but I did not found "automated export" or " configure "  on portal.

Comment: Ok, to clarify in manage.azure.com, I see this option after clicking DB on the left side and then selecting the DB I want to work with and then going under configure....is your issue that you can't see anything under the "STORAGE ACCOUNT" dropdown?

Answer (score 0):

Databases are now automatically backed up and you don't need to set this up, this is what I found with playing with it today:

> Did you know we already backup your databases? You can restore
>   databases from automatic backups using the Point-In-Time Restore and
>   Geo-Restore capabilities. Learn more.

But if you need to maintain your own copies for longer periods of time: In manage.windowsazure.com, navigating to the DB and then "Configure" you will find this option.

[image]

Comment: The problem is that I need to keep the copy for unlimited time.

Comment: A copy or multiple copies?

Comment: One copy per day, so I need to keep the history.

Comment: Ok, see my updated answer, let me know if you still have issues after this

Comment: The limit retention is 90 days. And on this panel dont give me any option for storage account and I already made one storage account.

Comment: Can you please add screenshots showing your storage account and the lack of it under the drop-down?  Also 90 days is the current limit in the product.  Explain your use case

Comment: My customer asked me to keep the full history, medical software.   http://i.stack.imgur.com/Kqv0e.png
http://i.stack.imgur.com/cfyg9.png